# Margin changes in converting DVI to PDF

Tags: pdf, margins, dvi

I have a 1 inch  top margin in all the pages that I have in my DVI file. When 
I convert this to PDF however the top margin reduces! I am not sure why this is happening. Could someone tell me how to ensure a top margin of at least 1 inch in the PDF?

Comment: You should give a minimal working example of the problem

Comment: I apologize but I need to submit this urgently and I have never made a minimum working example so its going to take time.Could you give me some pointers to use that I can try on my own.Thanks

Comment: Which paper size do you expect to get, letter or A4? Do you produce PDF directly from DVI, using dvipdfmx? If yes, try `dvipdfmx -p a4` or `dvipdfmx -p letter`. In case you produce PDF via Postscript, is the intermediate PS correctly sized? Try `dvips -t a4`, if not and you want A4. The final PDF should be correctly sized, if you do conversion with `ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 ...` (or similar for letter). For Windows, the option must read `-sPAPERSIZE#a4`.

Comment: @rty: See the post on meta about [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for guidelines. Just make a small file which still shows this error. Could it be that the paper format changes, e.g. from A4 to letter of vice versa?

Comment: @Alexander : I am not sure how to use the dvipdfmx .I did dvipdf -p a4 input.dvi output.pdf and it didnt work

Comment: The following produces constant 1in margins in both DVI and PDF (using `dvipdf`) for me. It also works when using `letterpaper` instead. `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
` Please provide a MWE by yourself so we can see better what's going wrong.

Comment: @rty: Try to use `dvips` to convert DVI -> PostScript, and then `ps2pdf` to convert PostScript -> PDF. Then you can specify the appropriate paper size on the `dvips` command line. For example, to get the A4 paper size, first run `dvips -t a4 foo.dvi` and then `ps2pdf foo.ps foo.pdf`. For letter paper size, run `dvips -t letter foo.dvi`, etc. The paper size specified on dvips command line should match the paper size selected in the Latex source code.

Comment: And in future, I strongly recommend that you switch to pdflatex. It will produce a PDF document directly, without any intermediate formats, with the right paper size.

Comment: @Martin: (At least my version of) `dvipdf` internally runs `dvips` with default settings. Depending on the system configuration, dvips might use letter or A4 paper size by default. Hence if it works for you, it does not necessarily work for someone else...

Comment: @Jukka: Good point. However, `dvipdf` produced A4 with `a4paper` and letter with `letterpaper` so it took the papersize from the DVI file.

Comment: @Martin: In your example, it seems to be the `geometry` package that does the magic; without it, I get the default paper size (A4 on my system). However, I got the impression that OP already has a document that looks correct as DVI, and he only wants to fix the PDF conversion without tweaking the document – in that case, `dvips -t` will most likely fix it.

Comment: @rty: `dvipdf` is simply a wrapper around `dvips`+`ps2pdf`. Thus, you are going via Postscript, not directly from DVI to PDF using `dvipdfmx`. That is, you should use `dvips` and `ps2pdf` in succession with options set as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @Alexander: Please turn your comments into an answer -- that way, the question will be removed from the "Unanswered" list.

Answer (score 4):

As Alexander Grahn suggested - instead of using `dvipdf` you could do it in two steps:

1. Run `dvips` with the desired paper option, such as

   ```
   dvips -t a4 file.dvi
   ```
2. Run `ps2pdf` with the desired paper option, it takes the same as `gs` aka ghostscript, such as

   ```
   ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 file.ps
   ```

I recommend using pdfLaTeX for directly producing PDF without those conversions, it has further benefits for example its microtypographic capabilities.