# DVI to PDF Converter

Tags: pdf, dvi

I am converting a dvi file to a pdf, but in that process my figures are misplaced. I used `\FloatBarrier` command to fix the figures in dvi, but facing the same problems in pdf. Can any one help?

Comment: Try to convert to `ps` first.

Comment: Exactly how are you coing from dvi to pdf? I know of at least two methods, so more detals would be helpful. And why don't you just work exclusively in PDF?

Comment: You need to take care that the paper format is not changed in conversion. E.g. if you use A4 paper size. The default is letter and in the conversion dvi->ps->pdf this might get mixed. See here for details: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21769/margin-changes-in-converting-dvi-to-pdf?rq=1

Comment: What is your OS? On linux, you could try `dvips your_file.dvi` and then `ps2pdf your_file.ps` in the terminal.

Comment: The pagination shouldn't be changing when converting from .dvi to .pdf --- the problem instead should be that the figures are showing up in the wrong place, which is a different problem. See this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: @ sigur i did that too but problem persists.

Comment: @dalief i am generating dvi first in latex and then simply click on dvi to pdf. and all my figures are in eps format which do not work in pdf.

Comment: @Martin thanks a lot. my problem is removed

Comment: @thanks all for the prompt response. it gives me a clear understanding.

Answer (score 35):

There's a utility called `dvipdfm` that can do this. It probably came with your TeX distribution. Try this at the command line:

`dvipdfm myfile.dvi`

This should create a file called `myfile.pdf`. If you run into trouble, the documentation can be found in http://gaspra.kettering.edu/dvipdfm/.

Comment: The documentation can also be found within the TeX distributions. And I would prefer `dvipdfmx`. Not to forget the way DVI —> PS —> PDF with first `dvips` and then `ps2pdf`.